# Objective C - how to convert Degree-Minute-Second to Double

Tags: objective-c, ios, mapkit

My actual problem is - How to obtain a CLLocation Object when the *coordinate* value on the map is available in Degree-Minute-Second form (as a String), instead of Double.

So, I am Looking for a way to convert Degree-Minute-Second to Double, which i can use to form a CLLocation object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with a bit of a cleaner answer when figuring this out

```
// split the string to deal with lat and lon separately
NSArray *parts = [dmsString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSString *latStr = parts[0];
NSString *lonStr = parts[1];

// convert each string
double lat = [self degreesStringToDecimal:latStr];
double lon = [self degreesStringToDecimal:lonStr];

// init your location object
CLLocation *loc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat longitude:lon];
```

**The magic**

```
- (double)degreesStringToDecimal:(NSString*)string
{
    // split the string
    NSArray *splitDegs = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"\u00B0"];  // unicode for degree symbol
    NSArray *splitMins = [splitDegs[1] componentsSeparatedByString:@"'"];
    NSArray *splitSecs = [splitMins[1] componentsSeparatedByString:@"\""];

    // get each segment of the dms string
    NSString *degreesString = splitDegs[0];
    NSString *minutesString = splitMins[0];
    NSString *secondsString = splitSecs[0];
    NSString *direction = splitSecs[1];

    // convert degrees
    double degrees = [degreesString doubleValue];

    // convert minutes
    double minutes = [minutesString doubleValue] / 60;  // 60 degrees in a minute

    // convert seconds
    double seconds = [secondsString doubleValue] / 3600; // 60 seconds in a minute, or 3600 in a degree

    // add them all together
    double decimal = degrees + minutes + seconds;

    // determine if this is negative. south and west would be negative values
    if ([direction.uppercaseString isEqualToString:@"W"] || [direction.uppercaseString isEqualToString:@"S"])
    {
        decimal = -decimal;
    }

    return decimal;
}
```

Note that I've only tested this with coordinates in Wisconsin, which is North and West. I'm using [this tool](http://www.fcc.gov/encyclopedia/degrees-minutes-seconds-tofrom-decimal-degrees) to verify my calculations.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a the coordinate value in a String -

**Split the String To obtain Degree-Minute-Second values in separate strings.**

- `NSString *longlat= @"+39° 44' 39.28", -104° 50' 5.86" "`(find a way to escape the `"` in the string)

  ```
  //separate lat and long
  NSArray *splitLonglat = [longlat componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

  //separate Degree-Minute-Seconds
  NSArray *arrayLat = [[splitLonglat objectAtIndex:0] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
  double latitude,longitude;
  if([arrayLat count]==3){
  //get the double value for latitude
  latitude= [self convertDMSToDD_deg:(NSString *)[arrayLat objectAtIndex:0]//degree
                                 min:(NSString *)[arrayLat objectAtIndex:1]//minute
                                 sec:(NSString *)[arrayLat objectAtIndex:2]//seconds
            ];
  }else{
           //some values could be in decimal form in the String already, instead of Degree-Minute-Second form and we might not need to convert them.
           NSLog(@"latitude in decimal for %@",locationModelObject.name);
           latitude=[[splitLonglat objectAtIndex:0]doubleValue];
  }
  NSArray *arrayLong= [[splitLonglat objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
              if([arrayLong count]==4){
                  //get the double value for longitude
                  longitude= [self convertDMSToDD_deg:(NSString *)[arrayLong objectAtIndex:1]//degree
                                                  min:(NSString *)[arrayLong objectAtIndex:2]//minute
                                                  sec:(NSString *)[arrayLong objectAtIndex:3]//seconds
                              ];
              }else{
                  //some values could be in decimal form in the String already, instead of Degree-Minute-Second form and we might not need to convert them.
                  NSLog(@"longitude in decimal for %@",locationModelObject.name);
                  longitude=[[splitLonglat objectAtIndex:1]doubleValue];
              }
              //add latitude longitude to the model object
              locationModelObject.latitude=latitude;
              locationModelObject.longitude=longitude;
  ```

**The Method which does the conversion**

```
-(double) convertDMSToDD_deg:(NSString*)degrees min:(NSString* )minutes sec:(NSString*)seconds {

int latsign=1;

double degree=[degrees doubleValue];
double minute=[minutes doubleValue];
double second=[seconds doubleValue];
if (degree<0){
    latsign = -1;
}
else{
    latsign=1;
}
double dd = (degree + (latsign* (minute/60.)) + (latsign* (second/3600.) ) ) ;
return dd;
}
```

Comment: Calling it `decimalDegreesForDegrees:minutes:seconds:` would conform to the Cocoa naming conventions.

Comment: i'm quite new to objective-c, didn't know that.Thanks.