# Objective C - Convert DMS to LAT LONG (South and East)

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, coordinates

*Heads up, I'm an absolute newb when it comes to OBJ-C!*

I'm currently putting together and IOS app and utilising pre-loaded data listings/locations from my client. The coordinates to each listing/location has are in DMS, eg

```
S:35 00.065
E:148 06.660
```

There are thousands of listings and I can't go and change this over for each one. I'm currently importing that data via a WordPress JSON API (WP REST API Plugin). The app I'm making pulls that JSON data in and populates accordingly.

The format is simply 'east' and south' from the JSON URL.

```
http://example.com/api/get_recent_posts/?custom_fields=name,east,south,image,address,type,Postend&page=%ld
```

I have no idea how to convert the east and south into lat and long for the code. Everything is ready to go except this predicament!

*Everything I find on here leads to expired or dead links for their respective tutorials, in Javascript, PHP, or is reversing LAT LONG to DMS. :(*

Thanks in advance!

--- **EDIT WITH POSSIBLE ANSWER** ---

Thanks to @ronak-chaniyara for the answer. Just having troubles implementing into current code. Existing code from template below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad

{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSString *decodedText1 = [_restaurant.name stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&#8217;" withString:@"'"];
    NSString *decodedText = [decodedText1
                             stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&#038;" withString:@"&"];

    self.title = _restaurant.type;
    self.barname.text = decodedText;
    self.address.text = _restaurant.location;

    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];

    [self loadImageInNewThread];

    NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ht7" ofType:@"html"];
    NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    NSString *htmlString2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:htmlString,_restaurant.description];

    self.webView.delegate=self;
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString2 baseURL:nil];

    _webView.opaque = NO;
    _webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.306 green:0.306 blue:0.306 alpha:1];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar
     setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]}];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
    self.EntityPlot.delegate = self;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate1 = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(_restaurant.lattitude, _restaurant.longditude);
    EntityPlot *coordinate2 =  [[EntityPlot alloc] initWithTitle:decodedText Location:coordinate1];
    [self.EntityPlot addAnnotation: coordinate2];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D annotationCoord;
    annotationCoord.latitude = _restaurant.lattitude;
    annotationCoord.longitude = _restaurant.longditude;

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cream_pixels_@2X.png"];
    self.uiView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];

    [_barplot setRegion:MKCoordinateRegionMake(annotationCoord, MKCoordinateSpanMake(.005, .005)) animated:YES];
    [_barplot selectAnnotation:coordinate2 animated:YES];

    _barplot.showsUserLocation = YES;
```

**Me trying to implement:**

```
//Pass string DMS for Lat and Long

- (double)DMSStringToDecimal:(NSString*)strDMS
{

    // split the string
    NSArray *arrSplit = [strDMS componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];

    //direction
    NSString *direction = [arrSplit objectAtIndex:0];

    //degree
    NSString *degreesString = [[[arrSplit objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:0];


    NSArray *arrMinuteandSeconds=[[[[arrSplit objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

    //minutes
    NSString *minutesString = [arrMinuteandSeconds objectAtIndex:0];
    //seconds
    NSString *secondsString = [arrMinuteandSeconds objectAtIndex:1];


    // convert degrees
    double degrees = [degreesString doubleValue];

    // convert minutes
    double minutes = [minutesString doubleValue] / 60;  // 60 degrees in a minute

    // convert seconds
    double seconds = [secondsString doubleValue] / 3600; // 60 seconds in a minute, or 3600 in a degree

    // add them all together
    double decimal = degrees + minutes + seconds;

    // determine if this is negative. south and west would be negative values
    if ([direction.uppercaseString isEqualToString:@"W"] || [direction.uppercaseString isEqualToString:@"S"])
    {
        decimal = -decimal;
    }

    return decimal;
}


#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad

{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSString *decodedText1 = [_restaurant.name stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&#8217;" withString:@"'"];
    NSString *decodedText = [decodedText1
                             stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&#038;" withString:@"&"];

    self.title = _restaurant.type;
    self.barname.text = decodedText;
    self.address.text = _restaurant.location;

    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];

    [self loadImageInNewThread];

    NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ht7" ofType:@"html"];
    NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    NSString *htmlString2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:htmlString,_restaurant.description];

    self.webView.delegate=self;
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString2 baseURL:nil];

    _webView.opaque = NO;
    _webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.306 green:0.306 blue:0.306 alpha:1];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar
     setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]}];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
    self.EntityPlot.delegate = self;


    // location crap

    NSString *latStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:htmlString,_restaurant.lattitude];
    NSString *lonStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:htmlString,_restaurant.longditude];

    double lat = [self DMSStringToDecimal:latStr]; //which gives lat=-35.018055555555556
    double lon = [self DMSStringToDecimal:lonStr]; //which gives lon=148.28333333333333

    // CLLocation *loc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat longitude:lon];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate1 = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lon);
    EntityPlot *coordinate2 =  [[EntityPlot alloc] initWithTitle:decodedText Location:coordinate1];
    // CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate1 = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(_restaurant.lattitude, _restaurant.longditude);
    // EntityPlot *coordinate2 =  [[EntityPlot alloc] initWithTitle:decodedText Location:coordinate1];

    [self.EntityPlot addAnnotation: coordinate2];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D annotationCoord;
    annotationCoord.latitude = lat;
    annotationCoord.longitude = lon;
    // annotationCoord.latitude = _restaurant.lattitude;
    // annotationCoord.longitude = _restaurant.longditude;




    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cream_pixels_@2X.png"];
    self.uiView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];

    [_barplot setRegion:MKCoordinateRegionMake(annotationCoord, MKCoordinateSpanMake(.005, .005)) animated:YES];
    [_barplot selectAnnotation:coordinate2 animated:YES];

    _barplot.showsUserLocation = YES;

}
```

Comment: You want to parse get `3500.065 and 14806.660` from  `S:35 00.065 E:148 06.660` ?

Answer (score 1):

May be you can do something like below, (from answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28545279/5575752):

```
NSString *latStr=@"S:35 00.065";
NSString *lonStr=@"E:148 06.660";

double lat = [self DMSStringToDecimal:latStr]; //which gives lat=-35.018055555555556
double lon = [self DMSStringToDecimal:lonStr]; //which gives lon=148.28333333333333

// Now create Location object
CLLocation *loc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat longitude:lon];


//Pass string DMS for Lat and Long

- (double)DMSStringToDecimal:(NSString*)strDMS
{

    // split the string
    NSArray *arrSplit = [strDMS componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];

    //direction
    NSString *direction = [arrSplit objectAtIndex:0];

    //degree
    NSString *degreesString = [[[arrSplit objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:0];


    NSArray *arrMinuteandSeconds=[[[[arrSplit objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

    //minutes
    NSString *minutesString = [arrMinuteandSeconds objectAtIndex:0];
    //seconds
    NSString *secondsString = [arrMinuteandSeconds objectAtIndex:1];


    // convert degrees
    double degrees = [degreesString doubleValue];

    // convert minutes
    double minutes = [minutesString doubleValue] / 60;  // 60 degrees in a minute

    // convert seconds
    double seconds = [secondsString doubleValue] / 3600; // 60 seconds in a minute, or 3600 in a degree

    // add them all together
    double decimal = degrees + minutes + seconds;

    // determine if this is negative. south and west would be negative values
    if ([direction.uppercaseString isEqualToString:@"W"] || [direction.uppercaseString isEqualToString:@"S"])
    {
        decimal = -decimal;
    }

    return decimal;
}
```

Do modifications as per your requirement.

Hope it will help:)

Comment: Thanks @ronak-chaniyara for getting back to me with your help. Just having troubles implementing it into the code I already have via a template. Are you able to let me know what I'm doing wrong? I'm getting an error. I've edited the original post.

Comment: The error is built into the app template; "Unable to fetch Listings". The data is pulls is similar to the test information. The only difference latitude and longitude are south and east.

Comment: sorry, but i can't help you with that@MichaelMarchment